AI generated answers promoting a personal app
I've been reading a lot of answers about how to react to AI-generated responses. There is one particular case, a user who answers based on AI and gives credit to the source of the answer. So far, everything is "correct", even though it is quite discouraging for regular users of the site: this user is the first to answer and to almost all the questions.
The particular problem is that the site that credits the source of the answer is an application created by the same user, which makes it spam. They use all the answers on SE to promote their own application.
All the answers are flagged by different users, but since they have their corresponding credit, the moderators cannot do anything.
Is there a solution?

Have you flagged them as spam?

I did: –All the answers are flagged by different users, but since they have their corresponding credit, the moderators cannot do anything.–

Does the user state that it's their own product? if not, try a custom flag, explaining all the answers by the user are generated with their own product with no affiliation declared.

I think it's a deeper problem, the moderators are aware of it. That's why I'm posting my question here.

@Danielillo There are places where the moderator(s) involved can get help on this type of specific issue with a problematic user, but that place isn't going to be MSE. Can you share which SE site it is?

ux.stackexchange.com

There are two very different things here. AI generated content, and self promotion. Please focus on one.

I don't think that qualifies as spam, since they are attempts to answer the question, properly mentioning the AI resource they're using, and disclosing that they are the creator of the AI app. However, it does sound like excessive self-promotion. The general policy regarding self-promotion is that "disclosure is necessary but not sufficient". And in this case there are additional factors: we don't know how thoroughly they verify that the AI output isn't hallucination, and the AI allows them to generate a large volume of answer text in a short time frame, flooding the site.

@ShadowWizard I think the question is quite clear that it is not about AI generated answers but about an unorthodox use of the site camouflaging self promoting products

@Danielillo Thanks - I don't know what they'll say, of course, but I'll try to reach out to those mods to give them some advice/guidance as a starting point on how to address this.

I am in contact with the mods and we have exchanged messages about the issue, but I think this particular case is a bit vague about how to proceed.

It is a complex situation, although I do think there's a way through it. Have you been chatting with them via flags? Or like via chat?

Flags and the site Meta. This site is receiving a fairly significant number of AI answers lately.

If you mean littlebro.app it seems to be a single user who is affiliated with that site, and most of their replies have had the promotional link edited out.

If the issue is the self promotion, why does it matter that AI is being used? What's the difference if the user would have just written it themselves?

If one wanted AI answers, they could have just used the app. Stack doesn't need to be the place where we collect generated content

For sites with a Gen AI Ban
First and foremost, remember that some sites have a Gen AI ban. You can check for this at the site's Gen AI policy page, which will be at its version of /help/gen-ai-policy. It's worth giving that page a look; if AI content is not allowed, that's an easy mod flag.
For repeated posters
If a user on, say, User Experience did this in a number of answers,1 that would be excessive promotion.

Excessive promotion occurs when a user answers the question, but then puts a link to their blog or website in their answer with or without disclosing that they are linking to their own website in multiple answers.

Excessive promotion runs afoul of the promotion rules, so it should receive a mod flag even though the affiliation is disclosed.
For one-time posters
If a user has only linked to their Gen AI tool once, I'd be really hesitant to call it spam. However, I would not be hesitant to downvote and/or leave a comment if the answer is of low quality or flat-out wrong.

1. Purely hypothetically, of course.
